# Why does HttpContext not derive from HttpContextBase?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Both have Request and Response properties, but I can't write a method that takes either HttpContext or HttpContextBase.  In some places either one or the other is available so I need to handle both.  I know HttpContextWrapper can convert in one direction, but still... why is it like this?

Comment: I came here to figure out how to convert a `HttpContextBase` to `HttpContext`. Your question contained the answer. The answer is `HttpContextWrapper` which derives from `HttpContextBase` and takes a `HttpContext` as a parameter to the constructor. So as the name implies, it wraps a `HttpContext` and makes it available as a `HttpContextBase`-compatible object. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4567707/955831

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`HttpContext` has been around since .NET 1.0. Because of backward compatibility reasons, they can't change that class. `HttpContextBase` was introduced in ASP.NET MVC to allow for better testability because it makes it easier to mock/stub it.

Answer (score -1):

This is an old question but I just had the same problem and the answer is in Gunder's comment.

Create you methods to use HttpContectBase and then wrap your context in a HttpContextWrapper when you want to call it from your code

```
public class SomeClass{
    ... other stuff in your class
public void MyMethod(HttpContextBase contextbase){
    ...all your other code 
  }
}
```

Usage

```
var objSomeClass = new SomeClass();
objSomeClass.MyMethod(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));
```

<del>I think HttpContext.Current will be null if you make this call via ajax,</del> I will investigate how to get the context and update this post.

Comment: I think you should still have an HttpContext even with Ajax calls