# How do I get an HttpContext object from HttpContextBase in ASP.NET MVC 1?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httpcontext

I'm working with some WebForms/MVC-agnostic tools, and I need to get an instance of `HttpContext` given a reference to an `HttpContextBase` object. I can't use `HttpContext.Current` because I need this to work asynchronously as well (`HttpContext.Current` returns `null` during an asynchronous request). I'm aware of `HttpContextWrapper`, but goes the wrong way.

Answer (score 260, accepted):

The simplest way is to get the application, [`ApplicationInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextbase.applicationinstance.aspx), and use its [`Context`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.context.aspx) property:

```
// httpContextBase is of type HttpContextBase
HttpContext context = httpContextBase.ApplicationInstance.Context;
```

<sub>(thanks to [Ishmael Smyrnow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/192217/ishmael-smyrnow) who noted this in the comments)</sub>

#### Original answer:

You can, especially if the `HttpContextBase` instance you've been handed is of type [`HttpContextWrapper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextwrapper.aspx) at run-time. The following example illustrates how you can do this. It supposes you have a method called `Foo` that accepts context as `HttpContextBase` but then needs to call a method in a third-party assembly (that you may not have the good fortune to modify) that is expecting the context to be typed as `HttpContext`.

```
void Foo(HttpContextBase context) 
{
    var app = (HttpApplication) context.GetService(typeof(HttpApplication));
    ThirdParty.Bar.Baz(app.Context);
}

// Somewhere in assembly and namespace ThirdParty,
// in a class called Bar, there is Baz expecting HttpContext:

static void Baz(HttpContext context) { /* ... */ }
```

`HttpContextBase` has a method called [`GetService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextwrapper.getservice.aspx) as a result of supporting [`IServiceProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iserviceprovider.aspx). The `GetService` override of `HttpContextWrapper` delegates to the `GetService` implementation of the wrapped `HttpContext` instance. The `GetService` implementation of `HttpContext` allows you to query for usual suspects like `HttpApplication`, `HttpRequest`, `HttpResponse` and so on. It just so happens that `HttpApplication` has a property called [Context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.context.aspx) and which returns an instance of `HttpContext`. So one gets at the wrapped `HttpContext` instance by asking `HttpContextBase` for `HttpApplication` via `GetService` followed by reading the `Context` property of the returned `HttpApplication` instance.

Unlike `HttpContextBase`, `GetService` does not appear as a public member of `HttpContext` but that is because `HttpContext` implements `IServiceProvider.GetService` explicity while `HttpContextBase` doesn't.

Bear in mind that `Foo` is no longer testable because it relies on being able to unwrap the underlying `HttpContext` during testing and which is next to impossible to fake/stub in the first place. The point of this answer, however, is to address the question, “How do I get an HttpContext object from HttpContextBase?”, *literally*. The illustrated technique is useful in those situations where you find yourself sandwiched between components you don't necessarily have the luxury to modify.

Comment: Very interesting answer, just used it myself in MVC to pass the HttpContext from an Error Filter to ELMAH for logging.

Comment: nice answer, bet that took a bit of digging? :)

Comment: great answer! I utilized that especially in my Elmah to MVC controller https://github.com/alexanderbeletsky/elmah.mvc.controller/blob/master/Areas/Admin/Controllers/ElmahController.cs

Comment: With an HttpContextBase, couldn't you call `context.ApplicationInstance.Context`?

Comment: @IshmaelSmyrnow Darn it, don't how I missed that among all the `Http*Base` variations returned by `HttpContextBase`. :P I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 30):

You can,

```
var abstractContext = new System.Web.HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
```

Comment: -1 this is the wrong way, this gives you the Base when you have the Context, not the other way around.

Answer (score 14):

You can't.

The whole purpose of `HttpContextBase` is to abstract away the dependency on the concrete `HttpContext` class. While it *may* contain a concrete `HttpContext` *(such as is the case with `httpContextWrapper`)*, other implementations may have absolutely nothing to do with `HttpContext`.

Your best option is to define a custom Abstract Factory that can get a `HttpContextBase` for you, since you can always wrap a concrete `HttpContext` in a `HttpContextWrapper`.

Comment: This, by the way, was horribly done - I understand wanting to have a setup for unit tests, and I understand layers of abstraction - but WTH are you supposed to do when you want to use existing ASP.NET classes which expect an HttpContext? (like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionidmanager.aspx)

Comment: Yep to test `IHttpHandler` implementations you end you having to put a sill number of abstractions in (Response wrappers) just for your unit tests, which doesn't feel right but ends up being the only option.