# calling return RedirectToAction("Activity") outside controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I am building a fluent interface and would like to call the code below outside my controller...

```
return RedirectToAction("Activity");
```

How would I design this method? I have:

```
    public FluentCommand RedirectOnSuccess(string url)
    {
        if (IsSuccess)
            ;// make call here...

        return this;
    }
```

Note: IsSuccess is set here:

```
public FluentCommand Execute()
        {
            try
            {
                _command.Execute();
                IsSuccess = true;
            }
            catch (RulesException ex)
            {
                ex.CopyTo(_ms);
                IsSuccess = false;
            }
            return this;
        }
```

I call my fluent interface:

```
var fluent = new FluentCommand(new UpdateCommand(param,controller,modelstate)
.Execute()
.RedirectOnSucess("Actionname");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could store an instance of the `HttpContextBase` as a field inside your fluent interface and when you need to redirect:

```
var rc = new RequestContext(context, new RouteData());
var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(rc);
context.Response.Redirect(urlHelper.Action(actionName), false);
```

Comment: Thanks, I allready pass in the controller and store it as a field and simply used _controller.HttpContext.

Comment: Out of curiosity do I use the overload: var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(rc); to pass in route data? e.g. taskid = 34

Comment: @Haroon, you could use it like this: `urlHelper.Action(actionName, new { id = taskid })`

Comment: You can get the current HttpBaseContext using `var context = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)`. (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3472045/37147)

Comment: The code sample from question expect to return value. But solution wont has return construction (Redirect is void).