# Mono ASP.NET MVC tilde in href causes System.NotImplementedException

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mono

I am trying to make an ASP.NET app using Mono 3.12.0 on Ubuntu 14.04.1. Whenever I try to use tildes in the hrefs in my `_Layout.cshtml`, I get a `System.NotImplementedException`.

I have made 3 different ASP.NET MVC Razor solutions with MonoDevelop and each one has the same problem.

My `_Layout.cshtml` file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="~/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/css/screen.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/css/print.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!--[if IE]>
        <link href="~/css/ie.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

I have also tried doing `Url.Content("~/css/file.css")` with the same error message.

Anybody know what's going on?

**UPDATE**

- `System.Web.Razor` is version `3.0.0.0`
- `System.Web.Mvc` is version `5.2.0.0`
- `System.Core` is version `4.0.0.0`

**UPDATE 2**

The complete error is:

```
System.NotImplementedException
The requested feature is not implemented.

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.

Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): System.Web.

Exception stack trace:
at System.Web.HttpContextWrapper.GetService (System.Type serviceType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Web.WebPages.UrlRewriterHelper.IsUrlRewriterTurnedOn (System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Web.WebPages.UrlRewriterHelper.WasRequestRewritten (System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Web.WebPages.UrlUtil.GenerateClientUrlInternal (System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext, System.String contentPath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Web.WebPages.UrlUtil.GenerateClientUrlInternal (System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext, System.String contentPath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Web.WebPages.UrlUtil.GenerateClientUrl (System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext, System.String basePath, System.String path, System.Object[] pathParts) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Href (System.String path, System.Object[] pathParts) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy (System.Web.WebPages.WebPageContext pageContext, System.IO.TextWriter writer, System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRenderingBase startPage) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy (System.Web.WebPages.WebPageContext pageContext, System.IO.TextWriter writer) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase+<>c__DisplayClass7.<RenderPageCore>b__6 (System.IO.TextWriter writer) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo (System.IO.TextWriter writer) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.WriteTo (System.IO.TextWriter writer, System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult content) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write (System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding (System.String partialViewName, System.Action`1 body) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy (System.Web.WebPages.WebPageContext pageContext, System.IO.TextWriter writer, System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRenderingBase startPage) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView (System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext viewContext, System.IO.TextWriter writer, System.Object instance) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render (System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext viewContext, System.IO.TextWriter writer) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult actionResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive (IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, System.Web.Mvc.ResultExecutingContext preContext, System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult actionResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive (IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, System.Web.Mvc.ResultExecutingContext preContext, System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult actionResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

Version Information: 3.12.0 (tarball Sat Feb 7 19:12:57 UTC 2015); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.17020
```

Comment: Not an answer, but I'm running Mono 3.6.0 without problem. My markup in _Layout.cshtml looks like: `<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/style.css")"...`

Comment: @chuex Hmm, I tried that markup, same error. What version of Razor are you using?

Comment: I'm on MVC 3 - I do my development in Visual Studio and push to my website which is running on linux. I see you are on MVC 5, wow. I can't even get 4 to work. Does your exception give any more information, such as the name of the function that is not implemented?

Comment: My System.Web.Razor dll shows version 1.0.20105

Comment: @chuex yeah, MVC 5 was default, I guess it must ship with the new Mono version. Under "details" in the exception I get: "Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): System.Web." I'll add that info to the post

Comment: OK, the complete exception is up now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [this commit on GitHub](https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/d35449e99bc1315657ec41de2c90661bb82fc66a#diff-4324c426d53ff23491eee60ac13c3c6e) which says that it adds the missing bits to support MVC 5.2. The commit was put in on October 2014.

The above commit shows that the function that was causing the error was updated, like so:

```
public override object GetService (Type serviceType) 
{ 
    throw new NotImplementedException ();
    return ((IServiceProvider)w).GetService (serviceType); 
}
```

According to your post you are running version 3.12. If I look at [the latest 3.12 version](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/mono-3.12.0.76/mcs/class/System.Web.Abstractions/System.Web/HttpContextWrapper.cs), the commit is not there yet:

```
public override object GetService (Type serviceType) 
{ 
    throw new NotImplementedException (); 
}
```

It appears you will have to either compile the latest version yourself, or wait until the next Mono release.

One other (untested) workaround, given the links in your post, is to not use the tilde:

```
<link href="/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for doing this research. I guess I'll just wait for the next version, and you are correct, not using the tilde works fine.

Comment: Hmm, just realized that the commit you referenced was from Oct. 2014. Do you think a new Mono version will be released soon, or should I just compile from source?

Comment: Never can tell when they are going to release. If this were me, I would go with the non-tilde workaround and wait for the next release. Compiling Mono from source can be a little daunting.

Comment: Yeah, that was my impression as well. Do you happen to know if any other functions besides the tilde thing are affected by that commit?